# Creating a field that is partially filled and can partially be edited

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a table with many data rows. This table contains the field "title".
Some of the data rows have already something predefined in that field and the other data rows have this field empty.

My goal is to create a form where users can do the following for every data row: If the field "title" is filled, this field can't be edit. If the field "title" is empty, the user can write something in this field.

I haven't found a solution yet. I tried with calculated fields but these can't be edited.

Also this table and form are for web access, so the possibilities are limited.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try Conditional Formatting of textbox to set Enabled property. However, no idea if Conditional Formatting will work with web app.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I don't think that Conditional Formatting is compatible with web app because that option is greyed out all the time

Answer (score 0):

Run embedded macro in form OnCurrent event to execute SetProperty action. Use it inside an `If Then Else` conditional to set Enabled property.

```
If IsNull(Forms!formname!controlname) Then

    SetProperty
        ControlName: your control name
        Property: Enabled
        Value: True

Else

    SetProperty
        ControlName: your control name
        Property: Enabled
        Value: False

End
```

This code assumes field will not have empty string. I do not allow empty strings in fields.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works, but only if I have the main form open.
This main form is embedded as sub-form of a sub-form of a form (don't ask me why ^^. I'm a newb, but until this point all functions work as intended).
When I open the form in the final view (user interface), I receive the error message " Microsoft Office Access can’t find the form [MAINFORMNAME] you refer. The form you referenced may be closed or may not exist in this database. Microsoft Office Access may have encountered a compile error in a Visual Basic.". 
As soon I delete your macro I don't get this message anymore.

Comment: Then I suppose have to adjust the path in the IsNull expression. It won't be pretty. Something like: `Forms!MAINFORMNAME.subformcontainer1name.Form.subformcontainer2name.Form.controlname`

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was difficult to find the correct expression but finally it works. I can't thank you enough!
For other people that want to know what expression I used, it looks like the following: `IsNull([Forms]![FORMNAME1]![SUBFORMCONTAINER1].[Form]![SUBFORMCONTAINER2]![CONTROLNAME])`

Comment: Update: While it works in the access enviroment, I receive the following error message while using the form online in web: "Object does not support this property or method".
Will try to find a solution